# Shift users logins in php mvc environment

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication

I am trying to accomplish probably a fairly simple task, but I got stucked somewhere.

What am I trying to achieve: If I am logged in as an admin, I have the option to login as any of the users. After I login as the user, if I want to go back to the admin, I need to logout the user, and I will be redirected to the admin.

I have issue when trying to get back to the admin. If I login in some of the user accounts through the admin, then I set a session variable in my loging function that an admin has logged in into the account. And then when logging out, I check if that session variable is set. If it is set, then log the admin back to its panel, if not then just log out the user.

But it seems that it doesn't work like that... When I do the logout, I loose everything. I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this one. I can also paste the code if someone wants to take a look at it.

Here is the logging in code

```
if(isset($_POST['login']) || isset($adminInit)) {
    if(!isset($adminInit)) {
        // it is a regular user
        // clean POST input
        // return the user from the database
    }
    else {
        // it is the admin
        // return the user from the database
    }
    if(!empty(the database call)) {
        if(isset($adminInit)) {
            $this->session->adminID = $this->session->id;
        }
        $this->session->loggedIn = true;
        $this->session->id = $data['id'];
        $this->session->level = $data['user_level'];
        if($this->session->level == 9)
            header('location: ' . __SITE_URL . 'admin/');
        else
            header('location: ' . __SITE_URL);
    }
    else $printError;
}
```

And this is the logging out code

```
if(isset($adminInit)) {
    $this->session->id = $this->session->adminID;
    header('location: ' . __SITE_URL . 'authenticate/login/');
}
$this->session->destroy();
header('location: ' . __SITE_URL);
```

Comment: What is the code that performs the "logging you as user" part ?

Comment: How can I put the code as an answer your question? I did that, but I made a lot of mess.. Ok, I will edit my initial post.

Comment: Damn .. i actually meant "logging out as user"  .. cause of some brain-turd i managed to sway "you" and "out" .. sorry. But actually both logging in and out would be useful to find whats going on

Comment: I edited my initial post, and I added the logging out code, you can take a look at it.

Comment: Well .. thats where the problem is. Your `$this->session->destroy();`.

Comment: But how would I logout the user otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing session_destroy() on each logout. Instead you should implement [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) or some similar [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29) structure in session to hold the list of accounts.

And yes, you should keep all the account-chain in the session and actually accessible, because later you might need to not just "view account as user" but also be able to see some additional info "as admin".

Basically, what you need to implement is at login, you push new user details (most likely - as array itself). And on logout you pop the last active user .. then check what is the next item in the stack. If stack is empty, you log out completely (and maybe destroy the session). Is there is some account info still there - you redirect him/her to appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're loosing the session data - you are either loosing the session id (cookie that gets unset or invalid due to domain/path settings) or there's a session_destroy() hiding somewhere.

Comment: In my logout function, I put the admin session variable into the account session id, and I try to log the admin again. But it just destroys the session for some reason.